# Does DNA replication in 5' to 3' (leading strand) need RNA primase?

Tags: dna, replication, primer

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27TxKoFU2Nw

In the above video it shows that during DNA replication, the lagging strand require RNA primase to add 3' -OH group for further addition of nucleotides. However, it hasn't been shown that the above strand ( leading strand) require it.

Besides, RNA is needed to initiate the polymerization because it has the 3'-OH.
But when I look at the structure of deoxynucleotide, it also has the 3'-OH but it does not have the 2'-OH. So why DNA cannot initiate the polymerization?

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [DNA polymerase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_polymerase) also needs a RNA primer on the leading strand to be able to start polymerization. Afterwards this is not needed anymore, since the [replication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_replication) goes on without a break. On the lagging strand polymerization replication can only work between the replication fork and the next region of double-stranded DNA. See the figure (from [here](http://biology.tutorvista.com/cell/dna-replication.html)):

[image]

The reason for the need for RNA primers is located in the function of the enzymes. While the DNA polymerase can only work on a double stranded template (add nucleotides to the 3'OH-end of the strand) the [DNA Primase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primase) (actually an RNA polymerase) can work on single stranded targets and thus add the RNA primer there.

Comment: I see! DNA primase cannot work in double stranded template. Thanks a lot.